# R: Removing NA values from a data frame

Tags: r

A bit of a newbie question: I have a data frame with 7,000 observations of 15 variables and 800+ `NA` values.

I have figured out how to identify the rows with 4 or more `NA` values:
`DF[rowSums(is.na(DF)) >= 4, ]`, but I'd like to remove the records with 4 or more `NA` values from the `DF`.  Can someone let me know where to put the `na.rm = T` if this is the best way?

Many thanks, I'm new to `R` and have looked and looked...

Comment: Almost there: `DF <- DF[rowSums(is.na(DF)) < 4, ]`

Comment: Wow, sometimes you just can't see the forest through the trees.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition identifies the rows you want to omit. Negate it to ID the rows you want to keep, then store the result in the variable (or another one.):

```
DF <- DF[!(rowSums(is.na(DF)) >= 4), ]
```